# How to create a vector of JPanels?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel

I tried to add to a panel an array of subpanels defined in the class below ,but I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
public class PlayerPanel extends JPanel{
    public JPanel[] playerPanelArray;

    public PlayerPanel(int nrOfPlayers){    
        playerPanelArray = new JPanel[nrOfPlayers];

        for(int i = 0; i < nrOfPlayers; i++) {
            playerPanelArray[i] = new JPanel();
            playerPanelArray[i].add(new JButton("See if working"));
            add(playerPanelArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And still I don't understand why I have to initialize `playerPanelArray` twice like:

```
playerPanelArray = new JPanel[nrOfPlayers];
```

and:

```
playerPanelArray[i] = new JPanel();
```

If I remove the first one it get me a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: on which line you get an error?

Comment: To answer your second question, `playerPanelArray= new JPanel[nrOfPlayers];` is only initialising the *array*, whereas `playerPanelArray[i]= new JPanel();` is initialising each element *within* the array. You can think of the array as being like the container - you're just creating a box big enough to put `nrOfPlayers` elements in, but those elements don't exist until you call `new JPanel()`, which is what you're doing within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You first statement tells the compiler to allocate an array of `nrOfPlayers` that will contain JPanels. But none of the element is assicgned, they all contain `null`.

The second statement initializes each element with a new JPanel and puts their reference where it was allocated before. If you do not allocate the array first, the reference ihas nowehere to be put.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a vector you would need to use something like:

```
Vector<JPanel> panels = new Vector<JPanel>(); 
panels.add(new JPanel());
```

It currently fails because none of the elements are assigned, they currently contain null.

`playerPanelArray= new JPanel[nrOfPlayers];` is initializing the array, and `playerPanelArray[i]= new JPanel();` is instantiating the object at that specific index, which is currently null.

I would use ArrayList, I know you said in the title how to use vector but unless this is going to be multi-threaded, I think ArrayList would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why I have to initialize `playerPanelArray` twice

```
playerPanelArray = new JPanel[nrOfPlayers];
```

This just *initialized the array*. Any non-primitive types in the array must be initialized separately. If you don't initialize these array elements, they will be `null` which will eventually cause a NPE.

```
playerPanelArray[i] = new JPanel();
```

This *initializes the element at position `i`*. Of course, you put this in a loop and this way you initialize all the elements.

The code you posted for `PlayerPanel` works well. I suggest you compare it with the code in your current application and then post the part that causes the error.